# UIToolbar not showing up after segue to root viewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uitoolbar

I have a storyboard where at some point there is a push segue to the root/main viewController.

The problem is: my toolbar is disappearing when the segue is "executed". (The toolBar doesn't show up in the viewController that originally had a toolBar).

I tried to set in viewDidLoad() the isHidden property to false, also tried that in prepareForSegue() in the previous controller, tried to change the dropdown in xcode from inferred to translucent toolbar, and other several recommended approaches I found in here. None of them worked.

Example of what I tried:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
}
```

I was thinking that it could be because of my appDelegate code as I had a similar problem with the navigation controller, which I fixed just by setting up a navigation controller to the window.rootViewController like below. Any suggestion on how to fix the issue with the toolBar in an "elegant" way?

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let isUserAuthenticated:Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserAuthenticated")

    if(!isUserAuthenticated) {
        let loginViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginView") as! LoginPageViewController
        window!.rootViewController = loginViewController
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    } else {
        let protectedPage = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController") as! ViewController

        // this was necessary in order to instantiate the navigation controller and it show up in the page
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: protectedPage)

        window!.rootViewController = navigationController
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Push segue to root view controller? You should be using an unwind segue or popToRootViewController for this.

Comment: Hi ZeMoon. Thanks for your answer. I've changed to use popToRootViewController but the toolBar still doesn't appear.